# Why does getImageData give a large array?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

To analyze the pixel data in my HTML5 Canvas:

```
    var width  = 960;
    var height = 500;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myFigure');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = new Image("starry-night.jpg");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    var pixels = ctx.getImageData(0,0, width, height);
```

The length of the image data array I get to be `1920000` but when I multiply `960*500*3 = 1440000`  How come my computation is much smaller than the actual length?

Can someone explain to me the type [Uint8ClampedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

1920000 / 960 / 500 = 4 Because the array stores a 4th value for Alpha (RGBA not RGB)

Uint8ClampedArray means a array of (U)nsigned (Int)egers which are clamped (forced to have a highest value of) (8) bytes. 8 bytes of Unsigned integers allows for a unique combination of bits for up to 256 values (0-255). (If the integer was signed you could have half as many for positive and half for negative)

**Long Answer**

According to 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

> data = A Uint8ClampedArray representing a one-dimensional array
>   containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0
>   and 255 (included).

And

> The Uint8ClampedArray contains height × width × 4 bytes of data, with
>   index values ranging from 0 to (height×width×4)-1.

1920000 / 960 / 500 = 4

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray

> The Uint8ClampedArray typed array represents an array of 8-bit
>   unsigned integers clamped to 0-255; if you specified a value that is
>   out of the range of [0,255], 0 or 255 will be set instead. The
>   contents are initialized to 0. Once established, you can reference
>   elements in the array using the object's methods, or using standard
>   array index syntax (that is, using bracket notation).

Answer (score 3):

You receive RGB values and the Alpha value. Which means you have to do `960 * 500 * 4` which yields the correct result.